# Problems using a string list inside of another list

Tags: c#, list, class

Basically what I am trying to do is to load a book text file into a string array, then to break the individual pages apart into separate pages along with other properties of each page in the book. When I try to add a new item into the list of pages it does not keep the dailypages.pageText value after I call temp.pageText.Clear(). I am very new to C# and object oriented programming so it's likely that I am doing more than one thing wrong here :)

```
abstract class Book
{
  abstract internal void loadPages();
  protected string[] bookText { get; set; }  // Load entire book text into
  /// Other generic book properties

  public Book(string filename)  // Load the book
  {
    bookText = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
  }

  protected abstract class Page  // Generic page properties
  {
    internal int pageNum { get; set; }
    internal List<string> pageText{ get; set; }  // Single page from the book

    public Page()    // Init list of strings
    {
      pageText = new List<string>();
    }
  }
}

class DailyReflections : Book
{
  List<dailyPage> dailypages = new List<dailyPage>();  // Init list of Pages

  override internal void loadPages()  // Split dailypages from bookText
  {
    DateTime date = new DateTime();
    DateTime date2 = new DateTime();
    dailyPage temp = new dailyPage();

    for (int bookline = 0; bookline < bookText.LongLength; bookline++)
    {
      if (DateTime.TryParse(this.bookText[bookline], out date))
      {
        bookline++;
        while (!DateTime.TryParse(bookText[bookline], out date2))
        {
          temp.pageText.Add(bookText[bookline]);
          if (++bookline >= bookText.LongLength) break;
        }
        bookline--;
      }
      temp.dailyDate = date;
      dailypages.Add(temp);
      temp.pageText.Clear();
      this.totalPages++;
    }
  Console.WriteLine(dailypages[0].pageText[0]); 
//    ^^^ This line I get an out of range error, this should be line 1 of the 
//    first page. Same error with any index used. If I take out the line
//    temp.pageText.Clear(); (used to clear the text to fill it with the next
//    page, maybe I am using it wrong). Without the .Clear() dailypages[0]
//    contains page 1, [1] contains page 1 and page 2, [2] pages 1,2,3 since.
//    it continues adding to the end of temp.pageText without clearing the 
//    last page.
  }

  protected class dailyPage : Page  // Page with values unique to the book
  {
    internal DateTime dailyDate { get; set: }  // Date on the page
    internal string pageTitle { get; set; }  // Title of the page
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using nested abstract classes?

Comment: What do you mean "does not keep the pageText value" ? You called `pageText.Clear()` didn't you?

Comment: I am not sure if this is the right way to do this, but the intention is to have Book and its members as well as Page and its members to be a general common ground prototype used for inheriting to a class that will contain any unique properties or procedures.

Comment: Yes, I call .Clear() to clear temp.pageText after "saving" the data to dailypages.pageText. Yet when I try to access dailypages.pageText after the temp.pageText.Clear() it gives an error. Although I can still access the same page's dailypages.dailyDate without issue after using temp.pageText.Clear().

Comment: What is dailyPages and how/when/where do you access it when you get the data correctly and when you get the error? You seem to be assuming that Add function creates a new object instance, which it likely isn't.

Comment: dailyPages is a single page with properties of that page (day of the year on the page, page #, page title, page's text). dailypages is a list of dailyPages. I understand that Add() puts another item at the end of a list, and I have =new declarations for each class object and object list to the best of my understanding. I just added a simple line of code with comments of how and what happens when I try to access dailypages.pageText.

Comment: I believe that you need to move `temp = new dailyPage();` into the for loop and comment out the Clear() call

Comment: I second @o_weisman 's approach. The reason is that `temp` is a reference (because `dailypage` is a `class`). If you insert `temp` in a list and then clear part of the `temp`'s members, they'll be cleared also in the list, since it's the same reference. Effectively you end up with a list consisting of identical members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading the entire book into an array, and then breaking that array up and adding to separate pages might be an inefficient way to go about it, since you're effectively storing the book twice in memory, and processing it twice, once to load, and once to parse pages.

It's a bit hard to tell if an interface or abstract approach is the best way to go, but since you're loading the pages in your concrete class, an interface might be simpler.

Here's an incomplete example of how you could read and process the book in a single pass:

```
public interface IBook
{
    // List might be too specific, IEnumerable might work fine
    List<IPage> Pages { get; set; }

    // ctor loading is ok, but harder to unit test and define via interface
    void LoadPages(string fileName); 
}

public interface IPage
{
    int Number { get; set; }
    string Text { get; set; }
}

public class DailyReflections : IBook
{
    List<IPage> Pages { get; set; }

    public void LoadPages(string fileName)
    {            
        // Read one line at time, perhaps by appending line to StringBuilder
        // Attempt to parse date on this line, then when your date parses, 
        // create new DailyPage from StringBuilder text and date, then add to Pages.
        // Then clear your StringBuilder and continue until all lines are read.
        // e.g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx
    }
}

public class DailyPage : IPage
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

You could break this up further, for example by having a BookReader class, or creating interfaces IDailyReflections and IDailyPage, but unless you're going to need them elsewhere, it may not be worthwhile.

I'd also advise setting up unit tests to verify that your approach is working, and edge cases are dealt with (e.g. no date on first|last page). You might then discover it's better to pass a stream to LoadPages rather than a filename, thereby avoiding the assumption that the book is always a file, and making both your unit testing simpler to implement (in-memory stream vs file on disk), and your book reading more flexible (load from file, load from web, etc.).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will need to look into Interfaces and IEnumerators more deeply to wrap my head around them. I will likely find them to be valuable as I learn more. The Interface idea at first seemed like a good idea, but having to rewrite all of the properties into each inheritance of the interface required more code than was needed for certain properties that wouldn't vary between child classes of Book. I am glad to see how dynamic a plain old string can be in C#!

Answer (score 0):

After some experimenting I found the primary reason why the code wasn't working correctly. I turned pageText into a string to make things simpler (it is no longer a list within a list now) and eliminate potential problems. The main issue is on the line where I was trying to add a new page to the list of pages. The issue wasn't necessarily the list within the list. I was calling dailypages.Add(temp); which was not creating a new instance of dailypages at the end of the list, but simply pointing to the location of temp in memory. When I called temp.pageText.Clear() it would also effectively clear and make null dailypages.pageText since they were both referring to the same memory block.

So this problem was eliminated by replacing dailypages.Add(temp) with dailypages.Add(new dailyPage) which reserves a new block of memory specific to the dailyPage type. If I were to keep the dailypages.pageText as a list I would have needed to dailypages[totalPages-1].pageText.Add(new string) for each new list item created for dailypages to get my list within a list to work. I will post the "repaired" code, but as I am still very new to C# I am sure you veterans will spot many newbie errors :) I am far from finished with this code, but I thought I would post the solution I found to my earlier question. I got some useful information out of the posts.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Books
{
    abstract class Book // Class prototype for a book from a text file
    {
        public string bookTitle { get; set; } // the title
        public string bookSubTitle { get; set; } // subtitle
        public string bookAuthor { get; set; }  // author
        protected string[] bookText { get; set; } // book's text
        protected int totalPages { get; set; } // Total number of pages
        public Boolean loadError = false;     // file not found marker
        abstract internal void loadPages(); // seperates pages

        // Generic class constructor
        public Book(string filename)
        {
            if (File.Exists(filename)) // does text file book exist?
                bookText = File.ReadAllLines(filename); //load bookText
            else
            {
                loadError = true;// File was not found
                ErrorMessage("File \"" + filename + "\" is missing.                             
                  \nClosing program.");
            }
        }

        // Displays an error message
        private static void ErrorMessage(string str)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine(str);
            Console.ResetColor();
        }

        // Prototype class for a page
        protected abstract class Page
        {
            internal int pageNum { get; set; }
            internal string pageText { get; set;}
        }
    }

    // Class used specifically for the "Daily Reflections" book
    class DailyReflections : Book
    {
        List<dailyPage> dailypages = new List<dailyPage>();
        private DateTime today = DateTime.Now;

        // Organizes pages from bookText[] into dailypages list
        internal void loadPages()
        {
            DateTime date = new DateTime();
            DateTime date2 = new DateTime();
            string temptitle;
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

            for (int bookline = 0; bookline < bookText.LongLength;                    
              bookline++)
            {
                if (DateTime.TryParse(bookText[bookline], out date))
                {
                    bookline++;
                    temptitle = bookText[bookline].Trim();
                    while (!DateTime.TryParse(bookText[bookline], out                         
                      date2))
                    {
                        str.AppendLine(bookText[bookline]);
                        if (++bookline >= bookText.LongLength) break;
                    }
                    bookline--;
                    dailypages.Add(new dailyPage());
                    dailypages[totalPages].pageDate = date;
                    dailypages[totalPages].pageText = str.ToString();
                    dailypages[totalPages].pageNum = totalPages + 1;
                    dailypages[totalPages].pageTitle = temptitle;
                    str.Clear();
                    totalPages++;
                }
            }
        }

        // Class constructor unique to DailyReflections
        public DailyReflections() : base("Daily Reflections.txt")
        {
            this.bookTitle = "Daily Reflections";
            this.bookSubTitle = "";
            this.bookAuthor = "";
            loadPages();
        }

        // Display all lines of bookText
        public void printText()
        {
            foreach (dailyPage txt in dailypages)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(txt);
            }
        }

        // Page[] unique to DailyReflections
        protected class dailyPage : Page
        {
            internal DateTime pageDate { get; set; }
            internal string pageTitle { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```